# Fixing a bug in my simple digit program (C)

Tags: c, debugging

Welp, I have been tasked with writing a program which, if executed with a number in the commandline, counts the different digits and puts out the recurring ones, like this:

```
./digitcount 31344842
"3" occurs 2 times.
"4" occurs 3 times.
```

However, I just cant get it to work:

```
int n = input;
int digit_count = 0;
while(n!=0)                     //count amount of digits in input
{
    digit_count++;
    n /= 10;
}
int digit_array[digit_count];   //create array for digits

int i = digit_count;
while(i!=0)                     //assign digits to array elements
{
    digit_array[i-1] = input % 10;
    input /= 10;
    i--;
}

//count number of times a digit has appeared
int digit_amount[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int digit = 0;
while(digit<10)
{
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= digit_count)
    {
        if(digit_array[j] == digit)
        {
            digit_amount[j]++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    digit++;
}
//final output
printf("Repeated digits:\n");
int k = 0;
while(k<10)
{
    if(digit_amount[k] >= 2)
    {
        printf("\"%i\" occurs %i times.\n",k,digit_amount[k]);
    }
    k++;
}
```

When I compile the program, no errors/warnings show up, yet upon execution I only get:

```
Repeated digits:
```

I tried around quite a bit with it and deduced that everything works up until the program starts counting the occurance of digits, then every number is counted to be included once, and just once.

Does anyone know what happened here?
PS: I'm quite a scrub at programming, so please take kindly to me if I made some really dumb error :P

EDIT:

The part missing at the top is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   
   int input = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Comment: How and what is `input` set to? Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: int digit_array[digit_count]; would not work.. read up on dynamically allocated arrays (malloc)

Comment: Please include your `main()` method. For example, do you correctly convert `argv[1]` (ie. the number) from a `char*` to an `int`?

Comment: @gidim In what way would it not work? It's called a VLA (variable length array). Supported since c99 if I recall correctly.

Comment: @kaylum - true. Although not sure if I should delete my comment since it is compiler/c version dependent.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i added the left out rest.

Answer (score 0):

You unnecessarily complicated this task by introducing a second array. I tried to follow your thinking but gave up, and wrote this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("no input?\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int digit_amount[10] = {0};
    int input = atoi(argv[1]);

    while (input)
    {
        digit_amount[input % 10]++;
        input /= 10;
    }

    printf("Repeated digits:\n");
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<10; k++)
    {
        if(digit_amount[k] >= 2)
        {
            printf("\"%i\" occurs %i times.\n",k,digit_amount[k]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A few random notes:

1. You don't need to explicitly set each member of `digit_amount` to 0. Just the first is enough to indicate to the compiler the entire array must be initialized to zero.
2. Since you are using `int` and `atoi`, you must remember to limit your input to positive integers only.
3. Counting digits can simply be done with increasing the array element `value % 10`.
4. While you seem to use `while` correctly, the correct type of loop to use when printing out is `for`. That's what it's for.
5. You will be receiving a warning from your compiler that you did not use `argc`. For safety, best add a test at the top so your input gets checked.
6. Similar to `int main` not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

## The Fix

You are incrementing the wrong index.

```
digit_amount[j]++;
```

should be

```
digit_amount[digit]++;
```

You can see the code working at https://ideone.com/ajbJnd

NOTE: that in the working code `int input = atoi(argv[1]);` was replaced with `int input = atoi("31344842");`. If you change it back it should work as is in your program!

## Different Way

A cleaner way to do this would be to use the input as a string instead of converting it to an int.

Code Example https://ideone.com/F0PTFz

Code Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char* input = "31344842";
    int digit_count = 0;

    digit_count = strlen(input); //count amount of digits in input


    //count number of times a digit has appeared
    int digit_amount[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int digit = 0;
    while(digit<10)
    {
        int count = 0;
        char* singleDigit[1];
        while(count <= digit_count)
        {
            // Subtracting the character 0 from a character will give you its real int value
            if((input[count] - '0') == digit)
            {
                digit_amount[digit]++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        digit++;
    }
    //final output
    printf("Repeated digits:\n");
    int k = 0;
    while(k<10)
    {
        if(digit_amount[k] >= 2)
        {
            printf("\"%i\" occurs %i times.\n",k,digit_amount[k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're just learning C. I don't know if you are familiar with strings and characters yet, or not. So let's look at two ways to get digits.

**The string approach**

First, you can take advantage of the fact that you know you are receiving a string command line argument that should consist of a series of ASCII digit characters. The ASCII digits are represented by the integer values 48..57 (base 10), or 0x30..0x39 (base 16). The digits run consecutively from 0, 1, ... 9, so you can do string comparisons easily and you can do simple math. Specifically, `d - '0'` will convert a digit `d` into the numeric value of that digit.

```
const char * Usage = "Usage: myprog INT\n";

void
usage(void)
{
    print(Usage);
    exit(1);
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
        usage();

    const char * digitp = argv[1];
    int digit_val;

    while (*digitp) {
        if (!isdigit(*digitp))
            usage();

        digit_val = *digitp++ - '0';
        /* At this point digit_val contains a numeric value from 0..9 */
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

**The integer approach**

The string approach is the right way to go, unless you don't know about characters and strings or are somehow required to do it the other way by your class. In this case, we'll take some of your existing code:

```
int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
        usage();

    int number = atoi(argv[1]);

    do {
        digit_val = number % 10;
        number /= 10;

        /* At this point digit_val contains a numeric value from 0..9 */

    }
    while (number != 0);

    exit(0);
}
```

Note that these two skeletons are *different*. You might not care right now, but treating the value as a string allows for processing long sequences of digits that might cause an overflow when you call `atoi`. For example, a '1' followed by 2,000 zeros can be handled fine as a string, but cannot be represented as an integer on PC hardware.

Similarly, a parameter like "100x" might be parsed by `atoi` but will be flagged as an error by the string approach.

**Dealing with the digits**

Once you have a loop with each digit in it, what do you do? Your code was on the right track:

```
digit_amount[digit_val] += 1;  /* increase frequency count */
```

That's ALL! You're counting how often the digits appear, you don't need to do any more.

After the loop is finished, you can process all 10 frequency counts and see if any of them were repeated:

```
for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; ++digit)
    if (digit_amount[digit] > 1)
        printf("Digit %d is repeated %d times\n", digit, digit_amount[digit]);
```